Android name space error in building and running in emulator or any real device
# Trying to run application bu it display the name space error already tried with using bundle id and upgrading AGP version.
`Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

android {
    namespace 'com.example.namespace'
}

If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant; please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.
`

Tried to upgrading and downgrading sdk versions
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.namespace"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
//    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.3'
//    id 'kotlin-android'
//    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
//    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'





This question is similar to: How do I fix 'namespace not specified' error in Android Studio?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Add namespace to your module's build.gradle:
android {
    namespace = "your.namespace.here" // Add your namespace here
    compileSdk = 32

    /* Your default config */
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.applicationId"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    // Others
}


android {
namespace = "com.smartx.edc" // Add your namespace here
compileSdk = 32
/* Your default config */
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.smartrx.edoc"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

// Others

}
Still not working

Does it still throw the same error?

Yes still same error
